# Prestashop admin login error 302, CloudFlare and LiteSpeed server

Tags: caching, prestashop, cloudflare, http-status-code-302, litespeed

1. We have migrated a PrestaShop(PS) v.1.7.8.7 from an Apache server to a LiteSpeed server which includes the LiteSpeed cache module for PS and crawler enabled.
2. CloudFlare(CF) has always been in play with both the existing and the new server.
3. But when we enable "proxied" in DNS settings for the new server - then we suddenly can't login at the admin URL due to a 302 error. It looks like the login page is called 2 times in a row. All other functionality on the site works flawless.

Screenshots of the main-domain which is "proxied" via CF:
[image][image]

4. When we disable "proxied" in CF then we can login via the PS Admin page again as seen in the screenshot below:

Screenshot of the test-domain which is not "proxied" via CF:
[image]

The page just redirects to itself again and doesn't complain about wrong user credentials or similar.

We believe it's due to Litespeed's re-write logic. We have tried to disable the LiteSpeed cache module again (the LiteSpeed's rewrite rules are of course still unchanged even though the cache module has been disabled in PS) - and the issue remains. Somehow there is a conflict between CF and LiteSpeed in this setup which causes the redirect error. We know that WordPress has a CF module which enables CF and LiteSpeed's cache module to work simultaneously.

Comment: This is a common scenario when you forget to delete the /var/cache directory or have some issues with data integrity. It's probably not related to the Litespeed itself.

Comment: I tried yesterday to delete that folder - but the issue remained. Can you advise on how to troubleshoot this issue further. Thank you so much.